# App with multiple themes using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-theme, android-jetpack-compose

I want my app to provide options of having dark theme and light theme to the user, and the app's theme will become what the user selects.

How do I accomplish this with Android Jetpack Compose?

I had been going through the Android codelabs for app theming, and found the following code snippet:

```
@Composable
fun BasicsCodelabTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColors
    } else {
        LightColors
    }

    MaterialTheme(colors = colors) {
        content()
    }
}
```

But the above code is for changing the theme corresponding to 'system' theme, not what user selects in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `darkTheme` parameter to the value defined by the user.
The value `isSystemInDarkTheme()` is only the default value if you don't pass the parameter and you can also change this implementation as you prefer.

Something:

```
setContent {
    BasicsCodelabTheme(darkTheme = true /*user choice */) {
       //... 
}
```

Comment: 'BasicsCodelabTheme()' composable doesn't accomplish what I want. It responds to the SYSTEM theme selected by user, perhaps, from their device settings.

Comment: I want code that provides the user to select theme FROM APP.

Comment: @SparshDutta Just set the `darkTheme` parameter to the value defined by the user. `isSystemInDarkTheme()` is only the default value defined if you don't pass the parameter.

Comment: Oops  . . . . Thanks!

Comment: One question - setContent() will be called when the activity is created, but user will get the option to select theme after 'onCreate()' is called. So how will I call setContent() again after user selects a theme?

Comment: @SparshDutta use for example a state a view model